# How to filter values from a big JSON object with angular

Tags: angular

I want to get some data inside of thise data: [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa0rZ.png).
I just want to have the name, the position and the number of bikes available.
But I don't know how to do directly inside my service. I find a solution in the component by looping through my subscription but I am pretty sure it's not the good way, see below :

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { JcdecauxService } from '../jcdecaux.service';
import { DataBike } from '../jcdecaux/DataBike';
import { MarkerService } from './marker.service';

let datas: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-leaflet',
  templateUrl: './leaflet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leaflet.component.css']
 

})
export class LeafletComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

  private map: L.Map | undefined;

  private icon: {} = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '../../assets/velo_icon2.png',
    iconSize: [30,30],
    popupAnchor: [0, -10]
  })

  datas: any;
  filteredData:DataBike;
  arrayOfData:DataBike[]= [];

  constructor(private markerService: MarkerService, private jcdecauxService: JcdecauxService){}

  
    
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jcdecauxService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.datas = data;
      for(let data of this.datas){
        this.filteredData = {
          name: data.name,
          latitude: data.position.latitude,
          longitude: data.position.longitude,
          availableBikes: data.mainStands.availabilities.bikes
        }
        this.arrayOfData.push(this.filteredData)
      }
      console.log(this.arrayOfData);
      
    });
```

Could someone can enlighten me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just map it through the rxjs operator. It seems like you don't want to filter, rather select a few properties from it.

```
getData() {
   return this.http.get('something').pipe(map(bikes=>bikes.map(bike=>({
 
          name: bike.name,
          latitude: bike.position.latitude,
          longitude: bike.position.longitude,
          availableBikes: bike.mainStands.availabilities.bikes
        }));

}
```

Comment: Yes thanks after dealing with this map operator I finally succeed to do that ! Thanks for your reply